# Beautiful soup doesn't return full html

Tags: python, html, twitter, beautifulsoup

I've noticed that my code doesn't return the full html. Here is the code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

keys = "blabla" + " -filter:retweets AND -filter:replies"
query = "https://twitter.com/search?f=tweets&vertical=default&q=" + keys + "&src=typd&lang=es"
req = requests.get(query)
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text, "html.parser")

for tweets in soup.findAll("li", {'class': 'js-stream-item stream-item stream-item'}):
    print(tweets.get("data-tweet-id"))
```

This doesn't print anything and the "li" tag is not even in the soup object, nor the "div class='stream'", even though the twitter search page looks like this:

```html
  <div class="stream">
        <ol class="stream-items js-navigable-stream" id="stream-items-id">

      <li class="js-stream-item stream-item stream-item
" data-item-id="1211695349607174144"
id="stream-item-tweet-1211695349607174144"
data-item-type="tweet"
```

There is also a lot of other things which don't appear in my soup object.

Comment: Make sure your getting the right html doc from the request.

Comment: does it correspond with view-source? js won't run with requests

Comment: @MariosKeri how do i check that?

Comment: Just compare the html doc you get from requests with the html doc of the page you looking to scrap.

Comment: The html i get from the request is missing a few things. How do i get the right html?